# Connection String/Data Adapter Issues

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, excel

In my current project, I am to create a program that reads a new Excel spreadsheet daily (new one added daily to network filepath) and exports to database. I am getting this error whenever I try to write to a datatable variable:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): External table is not in the expected format.

Using the following code snippet, the error occurs at the last line:

```
            xls_sql = "SELECT * FROM [" & FN & "]"

        Dim dt2 As DataTable
        Dim myAdapter2 As Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        dt2 = New DataTable()
        myAdapter2 = New Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(xls_sql, Replace(My.Settings.xlsfile, "FileNameHere", FN))
        myAdapter2.Fill(dt2)
```

I think I have resolved the issue to be that, even though the program (that I have no knowledge of or access to) adding the daily Excel file lists them as .xls documents, they are actually formatted as .xml documents. My first clue to this is, when opening one of the sheets, it looks like a normal Excel table but when I go to "Save As", the default selected option is as "XML".

I am using this current connection string for XML:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\temp\FileNameHere;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";
```

as I had to look for a suitable one to replace my previous .xls string that I know works.

Is this string correct?
Could anyone shed light on my problem?

Comment: right click on xls file and open with notepad: it contains XML code? if so use .NET classes to read XML.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will solve your problem, but i have a function that imports xls spreadsheets. The connection string i use is like this:

```
Dim conexao_Excel As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;" _
                             & "data source=""" & arquivo & """;" _
                             & "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"

da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" & nome & "$] WHERE valor IS NOT NULL ", conexao_Excel)
```

It works perfectly for me. arquivo is the variable containing the path to the file, and nome is the name of the sheet.

Hope that helps.